# ASP.Net MVC 3 Image from other Assembly

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Assembly which hold all my Pictures.

How can I take one Picture of this Assembly in my MVC3 Assembly as an img?

```
img src="@Url.Content("?Link to other Assembly?")"
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are embedded resources in your other assembly, you'll have to create some sort of image handler and pass some sort of identifier, of the resource, to the handler and stream the resource from the assembly that way.

---

Create an ASP.NET Web Handler (.ashx file) that handles your image, pass the identifier to that image handler that will either display the image

Here is a quick tutorial on ASHX files: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do the same thing.  I just added a 'File' controller in my assembly that serves up the file as a FileStreamResult.  Then, the url becomes something like:

```
Url.Content("file/embedded/MyAssembly/Folder1/Folder2/image.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks work fine.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String filename = context.Request.QueryString["filename"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            return;

        var bitmap = this.GetImage(filename);

        if (bitmap == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, bitmap.RawFormat);
                ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```